# Custom url building rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating simple e-commerce website.
I don't want to use spree gem cause it has some problems with localization.
So I decided to build my own.
I will have some categories which i will take from database.
Let's say I take category `cars` And there I click on  `bmw x5 limited edition`
So I want to make browser address string look like
`http://mywebsite.com/cars/bmw-x5-limited-edition`

I need this for seo. I don't want to use get params like `mywebsite.com/cars/5?carname=bmw-x5`
Also there will be many categories and products which will be added to database through admin dashboard.
So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

define method in your `car` model

```
def to_param
  carname.to_s.gsub(/\s/, '-')
end
```

your URL would be `http://mywebsite.com/cars/bmw-x5-limited-edition`

but you need to find the record in the `show` action by the `carname` instead of `id` because now you are sending `carname` in place of `id`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You change your url by creating a to_url method in your cars model.

```
def to_param
    "#{name}"    #=> bmw-x5-limited-edition
end
```

FYI: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails

Comment: Definitely go check out this article. It's a pretty good one.

Answer (score 0):

This gem may also help you:  https://rubygems.org/gems/sanetitle. It does exactly what you want, removing special chars and putting everything in lowercase. You may also limit the number of chars in the returned value.